# pgfplots - bar chart with bars starting at -120 instead of 0

Tags: pgfplots

I would like a plot like the one here shown (wanted) 
As using `ybar`, the origin is fixed at 0, I'm getting a plot with the bars starting from zero instead of -120.

[image: bar chart wanted from MSexcel]

Comment: You mean the problem is about  representation of [-120,-90] ? So your Y-axis is not in this range ?
Could you show us some codes ?

Comment: ploting this using tikzpicture \ybar I m getting bar whichs start from 0, instead from -120.

Comment: You want to change the sign of your data ?

Comment: Can you post the code for your plot as a MWE?

Answer (score 3):

You can shift the labels with an offset

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\pgfplotstableread{
a b c
1 10 20
2 45 130
3 30 60
}\mytable
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ybar,xtick=data,enlarge y limits={upper=5},ymin=0,
yticklabel={\pgfmathparse{\tick-120}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}}]
\addplot table[x=a,y=b] {\mytable};
\addplot table[x=a,y=c] {\mytable};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ymax` and `ymin` in the `axis` properties. Consider following samples. Without setting parameters (Commented lines):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar=15,            
    %ymin=0,
    %ymax=120,            
    symbolic x coords={a small bar,a medium bar,a large bar},
    xtick=data]
    \addplot[ybar,fill=blue] coordinates {
        (a small bar,42)
        (a medium bar,50)
        (a large bar,80)
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Uncomment the lines and you will have different ranges for Y-axis:

[image]

Comment: getting same results with your code. Bars should be draw from -120 up to data level.

Comment: You can change the ymax and ymin value according to your problem.

Comment: thank you. but the problem is not range, but the bar origin point. Changing range will not affect the the bar origin, always they start from 0. The wanted chart is with bar staring from another value eg -120.